# Is the MacPort version of XQuartz severly outdated or what?

Tags: ssh, macports, x11, xquartz

At https://www.xquartz.org/ the current version of XQuartz is listed as 2.7.11 but in MacPort it looks like this

```
$ port search xquartz
xorg-server @1.20.5 (x11, devel)
    The X.org / Xquartz X server.

xorg-server-1.18 @1.18.4 (x11, devel)
    The X.org / Xquartz X server.

xorg-server-devel @1.20.4 (x11, devel)
    The X.org / Xquartz X server.

Found 3 ports.
```

The xquartz.org version is released 2016 so it is not like MP haven't had time to update. Am I missing something? Exactly what should I install if I want to run X11-applications using a SSH tunnel?

Answer (score 1):

XQuartz is itself dated but is the latest version and works well on High Sierra. The latest version is 2.7.11 dated several years ago. The [XQuartz homepage is here](https://www.xquartz.org). It can be loaded from the link. This latest? version should do what you want.

Comment: thank you.  I didn't mention anything about obsolete. I use XQuartz most every day.

Comment: That wasn't really an answer to my question. Besides, my question already linked to xquartz.org so clearly I was aware of where to download it.

Comment: You asked if it was outdated.  I've edited my answer to address that.